# Firefox JSON format error

Tags: json, firefox

When I execute the JSON formated code below, Firefox v20 will throw a `SyntaxError: invalid label` error.

```
{
    "aa": "bb"
}
```

but when I validate it using http://jsonlint.com/ it seems to be valid. So why is Firefox behaving like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place objects in places that are syntactically correct. For example, you can create an object like so:

```
var a = {"aa": "bb"};
```

Or you could pass that object to a function like:

```
func({"aa": "bb"});
```